# O que é o Google Polymer?

Tags: polymer

Vi alguns estudos recentes em sites estrangeiros sobre este [Google Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/), mas ainda não entendi onde ele deve ser utilizado, por exemplo em um aplicativo mobile.

Não encontrei blogs ou site brasileiros contendo informações sobre o Google Polymer.

Comment: Artigo para uma introdução. Vale a pena.
http://blog.dtisistemas.com.br/web-components-e-polymer-porque-ele-vai-facilitar-sua-vida/

Comment: Relacionado: [O que é Web Components](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160175/o-que-s%C3%A3o-web-components)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Polymer é uma biblioteca que facilita a criação de *[Web Components](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/)*, que são elementos HTML customizados, independentes e reutilizáveis.

A ideia é que você consiga criar seus próprios componentes apenas com HTML, os mesmos tendo um comportamento único e focado.

Vejamos o elemento `select`. Ele tem um único objetivo: **selecionar um ou mais item(ns) de uma lista de opções**. Podemos configurar seu comportamento com o **atributo** *multiple*, mas o objetivo principal continua o mesmo.

O mesmo deve acontecer com o elemento customizado `google-map`, citado na resposta de `@gtonioli`. Ele tem um único objetivo: **mostrar um mapa do Google**. Nele, podemos apontar de qual local queremos ver o mapa de acordo com os **atributos** *lat* e *long*.

Pode ser que ele mostre um pino em algum local passado pelo usuário, ou que ele mostre alguma rota de cidade a cidade, ou que ele aceite um atributo, chamado *zoom*, que mostra o mapa das coordenadas passadas de uma certa distância. Desde que o componente continue focado em **mostrar um mapa do Google**, essas funcionalidades são válidas.

---

Para fazer um *web component*, são utilizadas as seguintes tecnologias:

- *[Custom Elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/#custom-element-section)*

  Permite que nós, desenvolvedores, criemos elementos além dos especificados no HTML, registrando-os antes do uso.
- *[Shadow DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/#shadow-dom-section)*

  Permite a criação de elementos totalmente desacoplados do documento atual podendo, por exemplo, conter um ID que já existe no documento principal ou em outra *Shadow DOM subtree*. O CSS registrado nesses elementos não ultrapassa para o documento.
- *[HTML Templating](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/#template-section)*

  Permite a criação de templates, que podem ser levemente comparados com aqueles do *[Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#template)* e *[lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#template)*, em que uma marcação HTML é criada para ser utilizada futuramente.
- *[HTML Imports](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/#imports-section)*

  Digamos que é "um *[Require.js](http://requirejs.org/)* para HTML implementado pelo browser". São documentos HTML que são referenciados em outro documento como recurso externo.

Como essas tecnologias ainda estão em *Working Draft*, o Polymer contém vários *polyfills* que trazem parte dessas funcionalidades para os navegadores, ainda com algumas limitações, como os [HTML Imports sendo feitos por XMLHTTPRequest](http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#xhrrequests).

A biblioteca facilita o desenvolvimento dos *Web Components* deixando a criação de elementos customizados menos trabalhosa, com *two-way data binding* para o controle do componente e os *polyfills* citados acima.

Para uma introdução mais abrangente ao Polymer, veja [esses](http://youtu.be/VMVj_jR75vE) [vídeos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8OJ7ih8EE7s&feature=share&list=PLRAVCSU_HVYu-zlRaqArF8Ytwz1jlMOIM) (ambos em inglês, com legendas em inglês).

O site do projeto tem um [rápido tutorial](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/intro.html) para a criação de *Web Components* usando a biblioteca.

Answer (score 4):

Complementando a resposta do @Danguilherme segue alguns detalhes importantes:

### Benefícios

São muitos os benefícios do Polymer onde podemos destacar:

#### Programação Declarativa

Permite implementar Linguagem Específica de Dominio - DSL usando Markup poderoso, intuitivo, significativo e expressivo.

#### Composição à partir de Componentes menores

Blocos de construção usando composição

#### Manutenibilidade

Quando você lê o código você entende imediatamente diminuindo o custo de manutenção. O encapsulamento permite desenvolver componentes com função específica restringindo escopo e facilitando a manutenção.

#### Reusabilidade Real na Web

O encapsulamento valoriza a reusabilidade e o suporte de ferramentas como o Bower permite o uso por qualquer desenvolvedor

#### Extensibilidade

Implementa forma padrão para estender elementos nativos e elementos personalizados como no exemplo:

Podemos implementar a herança no Polymer usando:

```
<polymer-element name="my-car" extends="my-vehicle">
```

Temos a opção de fazer override dos métodos dos elementos do Polymer e, caso seja necessário, podemos utilizar this.super() para chamar a função do elemento herdado.

#### Separação de Escopo

Permite escopo diferenciado para CSS, DOM e APIs

#### Interoperabilidade

A integração é feita em baixo nivel no DOM assim a interoperabilidade é completa. Não é necessário usar outras bibliotecas JavaScript tal como jQuery pois podemos usar diretamente querySelector, querySelectorAll, getElementById, etc já que o IE 9 e todos os outros browsers já suportam isso.

#### Acessibilidade

Implementada por padrão.

#### Produtividade

Fica óbvio quando usamos devido a estas vantagens citadas acima.

#### Testabilidade

A testabilidade dos componentes é  provida pelo WCT - Web Component Tester
https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester

#### Mixins

Mixins servem para adicionar comportamento de objetos em outros. É uma feature do JavaScript. O Polymer possui um método utilitário para dar suporte a esta feature no Framework.

Gramática:

```
Polymer.mixin(target, obj1 [, obj2, ..., objN ])

Exemplo:
var myMixin = {
  sharedMethod: function() {
    // ...
  }
}

<polymer-element name="my-element">

<script>
 Polymer(Polymer.mixin({
   // my-element prototype
 }, myMixin));
</script>

</polymer-element>
```

#### Fontes no Github

Os fontes hospedados no github podem ser acessados via Bower

```
bower install --save Polymer/core-elements
```

#### Layout Containers

Diversos elementos para suporte a Layout elimina necessidade de uso do Bootstrap ou similar. Aliado a `Layout Attributes` que funciona para elementos nativos tal como  ou  temos um conjunto completo de funcionalidades para gerenciamento dinâmico de Layout.

#### Suporte a Temas

use  para implementar Temas para a aplicação

#### Suporte a Transições

Tags como  podem ser usadas para definir transições entre conteúdo de forma declarativa

#### Ferramenta de Design

Ferramenta visual disponível funcionando como playground para desenvolvimento de diálogos e páginas da aplicação usando drag-and-drop.

Answer (score 1):

Seria uma extensão para o HTML. Onde muitas funções seriam encapsuladas em tags HTML. Por exemplo adicionar um mapa com o Google Maps:

```
<!-- Import element -->
<link rel="import" href="google-map.html">

<!-- Use element -->
<google-map lat="37.790" long="-122.390"></google-map>
```