# Google Polymer e ANGULARJS (2016)

Tags: polymer

boa tarde. Alguém aqui utiliza o Google Polymer? Se já, possuem alguma experiência para contar sobre a possível integração dele com AngularJS?

Segundo o próprio Angular:
"A key feature of AngularJS 2.0 is its support for Web Components [1]. Google’s Polymer is a Web Component polyfill (enabling them on all current browsers) and a framework on top of Web Components."

Answer (score 2):

Eu uso o **Polymer** e não vejo necessidade de usar o **Angular** e explico porque. Para entender isso devemos responder a pergunta:

Como o AngularJS 2.0 e o Polymer estão relacionados ?

Resposta direta: eles não estão relacionados.

O Angular 2.0 foi totalmente reescrito com o intuito de se apoiar nos web-componentes usando uma abordagem própria com directivas angular. Você não precisa de Polymer para criar web-componentes no Angular 2.0 mas não é tão trivial fazê-lo.

Por outro lado o Polymer facilita muito a criação de web-components com seus polyfills.

O Angular é um Framework JavaScript com suporte a MVC.

O Polymer é uma API para web-componente. A vantagem que vejo no Polymer é a integração com o DOM onde você pode criar componentes herdando dos elementos HTML nativos e também pela enorme gama de elementos já existentes. A adopção do Polymer está aumentando muito dentro do Google que padronizou o Material Design no Android e o Polymer suporta dezenas de componentes com este paradigma visual/comportamental. Além disso a equipe do Google Chrome está trabalhando em estreita colaboração com a equipe do Polymer para suportar de forma nativa as características do HTML5 usadas no Polymer.

Já o forte do AngularJS é sua ampla adoção entre os desenvolvedores e é praticamente o framework javascript mais maduro existente hoje em dia, porém a maioria do código existente é da versão 1.x que não usa web-componente.

Algumas características interessantes do Angular 2 são: Dependency Injection, Templating, Anotações , Scaffolding e Touch Routing.

[Vantagens do Polymer podem ser vistas aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23619/o-que-%C3%A9-o-google-polymer/46558#46558)