# O que são Web Components?

Tags: html, component

O que são `web components` e como utilizar essa tecnologia ?

Gostaria de entender um pouco mais sobre essa tecnologia e visualizar um exemplo com seu uso.

Comment: Isso não deve responder totalmente sua pergunta mas esse link tem um artigo bem explicado sobre o assunto e mais alguns links de referência: http://tableless.com.br/web-components-introducao/

Comment: Massa vou dar uma olhada, vlw a dica...

Comment: Amei a pergunta, estava para perguntar isso agora +1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Os *Web Components* consistem em diversas tecnologias separadas, você pode entender um Web Component como sendo um widget que pode ser usado diversas vezes. Eles não precisam de bibliotecas externas/adicionais como jQuery e pode ser usado sem necessariamente escrever um script de código, por exemplo importar/injetar um widget (que neste caso é um trecho de html) para uma página HTML existente. Os Web Components não são completos ainda, sendo assim os browsers modernos suportam parte das tecnologias e outra parte ainda esta em desenvolvimento.

Web Components consiste em 4 tecnologias:

- [Custom Elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/) - Suportado apenas no Chrome 54+ e Opera 41+
- [HTML Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/#template-section) - Suportado em Chrome 49+, Edge 13+, Safari 9.1+, iOS Safari 9.3+, Android 4.4+ (browser nativo), Firefox 47+
- [Shadow DOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/) - Chrome 49, Safari 10, Android 4.4 com prefixo `-webkit` e Android 5.2 (Chromium WebView) sem prefixo
- [HTML Imports](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-html-imports-20130514/) - Chrome 49, Opera 40, Android 4.4 com prefixo `-webkit` e Android 5.2 (Chromium WebView) sem prefixo, Chrome 52 para Android

> **Nota:** esta resposta esta em construção

Comment: Mai num é obra do governo naum né ?

Comment: @MagicHat Web Components é bem mais coisas, os exemplos são vagos, algumas coisas ditas em uns artigos não tem sentido, não posso sair copiando e colando qualquer coisa aqui (tem alguns usuários que fazem isto), estou estudando os artigos conforme o tempo livre e estudando o w3.org ;)

Comment: Zuera mano... é que sei que suas respostas são bem esclarecedoras...

Comment: @MagicHat não estou dizendo que a resposta que você aceitou está errada, mas devido as variações nos artigos que li recomendo você confirmar primeiro, talvez esteja correta, mas a pessoa ali tem mania de Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V

Comment: Hehe... Faz parte, tem respostas que você precisa estudar fora da resposta para entender, pelas suas respostas que acompanho, são auto-explicativas... O fato de eu ter aceitado uma resposta não me impede de alterar se eu achar que outra está melhor...

Comment: É parece uma obra do governo mesmo....

Answer (score 5):

Nesse [artigo](http://www.devmedia.com.br/web-components-na-pratica/32476) do DevMedia diz:

> Segundo a especificação da [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/#introduction), os [Web Components](http://webcomponents.org/) consistem
>   em “um conjunto de cinco tecnologias: Templates, Shadow DOM, Custom
>   Elements, HTML Imports e Decorators”. Sendo que essa última, diferente
>   das demais, ainda não possui uma especificação e tem sido bastante
>   omitida pela comunidade.
>
> - **Templates**: descreve um método para declarar subárvores DOM inertes em HTML e manipulá-los para instanciar fragmentos de documento
>     com conteúdos idênticos.
> - **Shadow Dom**: descreve um método de estabelecer e manter limites funcionais entre árvores DOM e como estas árvores interagem uns com os
>     outros dentro de um documento, permitindo assim melhor encapsulamento
>     funcional dentro do DOM.
> - **Custom Elements**: descreve o método para permitir que o autor defina e use novos tipos de elementos DOM em um documento.
> - **HTML Import**: são uma forma de incluir e reutilizar documentos HTML em outros documentos HTML.
> - **Decorators**: Aplicam os templates com base em seletores CSS e JavaScript para criar mudanças visuais e comportamentais. O elemento
>     `content` inserido dentro do template será substituído com o conteúdo
>     do elemento de decoração.

A explicação de cada um desse elementos está parcialmente baseada no artigo [Web Components](http://betomuniz.com/blog/web-components-hoje/) do blog do Beto Muniz.

**Custom Elements**

> *Custom Elements* possibilita de forma bem explícita a criação de elementos diferenciados, transformando o desenvolvedor num "web
>   maker", ou seja, o desenvolvedor deixa de ficar limitado a apenas
>   `<button>`, `<div>`, etc. Podendo criar seus próprios elementos HTML
>   com estrutura, comportamento e estilo único.

Por exemplo, a estrutura do `Carousel` do Twitter `Bootstrap`:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

> Imagine poder encapsular todo esse `divnation` ou `listnation` junto
>   com lógica e estilo do `Carousel` e exibir apenas isso publicamente:

```
<my-carousel>
  <img src="images/x.jpg" alt="imagem X">
  <img src="images/y.jpg" alt="imagem Y">
  <img src="images/z.jpg" alt="imagem Z">
  ...
</my-carousel>
```

E repare principalmente que agora temos um elemento customizado chamado: `<my-carousel>`.

**Templates**

Onde são definidos o código reusável, começa com a tag `<template>`. É apenas um elemento declarativo para criar um novo modelo.

```
<template id="exemploTemplate">
  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="" class="imagemAvatar">
    <div class="nomeAvatar"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

JavaScript:

```
var template = document.querySelector('#exemploTemplate');
template.querySelector('.imagemAvatar').src = 'imagemPerfil.jpg';
template.querySelector('.nomeAvatar').textContent = 'Nome'; 
document.body.appendChild(template);
```

Isso é apenas JavaScript, não há novas APIs ou algo confuso.

**Shadow DOM**

> Foi pensado para permitir certa independência e isolamento do
>   componente, para que o mesmo seja assegurado de que nada externamente
>   e fora dos planos do que foi pensado para o elemento seja modificado.
>   Por exemplo a tag `<video>`:

```
<video width ="320" height="240" controls>
    #shadow-root (user-agent)
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <input type="button">
                <input type="range" step="any" max="12.612">
                    <div style="display: none;">0:00</div>
                    <div>0:12</div>
                <input type="button">
                <input type="range" step="any" max="1">
                <input type="button" style="display: none;">
                <input type="button">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    "Your browser does not support the video tag"
</video>
```

> Ele possui uma declaração `#shadow-root`, e é a partir desta
>   declaração que o "confinamento" do comportamento do seu elemento é
>   respeitada pelo browser e por sua aplicação, sem contar também que a
>   partir desta declaração uma subárvore de DOM é criada, o que também
>   evita assimilar este padrão ao uso de `<iframe>`. Se não fosse
>   possível criar este isolamento, todos os controles por exemplo da tag
>   `<video>` seriam afetados caso fosse crida uma regra CSS ou
>   manipulação global via Javascript para o elemento `div`.

**HTML Imports**

Importar dependências em nossa linguagem de escolha vem em muitas formas e tamanhos. Para CSS, temos `@import`, Para JavaScript em módulos ES6 que temos `import {Module} from './somewhere';`, E finalmente, HTML. Podemos importar componentes HTML na parte superior do nosso documento para definir quais nós precisamos usar no nosso aplicativo:

```
<link rel="import" href="customelements/my-carousel.html">
```

E assim, podemos declarar o mesmo elemento em qualquer lugar e momento dentro da página.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="import" href="customelements/my-carousel.html">
</head>
<body>

    <my-carousel>
      <img src="images/x.jpg" alt="imagem X">
      <img src="images/y.jpg" alt="imagem Y">
    </my-carousel>

    <my-carousel>
      <img src="images/a.jpg" alt="imagem A">
      <img src="images/b.jpg" alt="imagem B">
    </my-carousel>

</body>
```

**Decorators**

Decorators são parte da Web Components, mas na verdade não têm especificação. Aparentemente eles podem parecer algo assim, com a intenção de melhorar ou substituir a apresentação de um elemento existente.

```
<decorator id="detalhe">
  <template>
    <a id="resumo">
      &blacktriangledown;
      <content select="resumo"></content>
    </a>
    <content></content>
  </template>
</decorator>
```

Referências:

- [Web Components na prática](http://www.devmedia.com.br/web-components-na-pratica/32476)
- [Web Components](http://betomuniz.com/blog/web-components-hoje/)