# O que é shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-component

Quando eu estava lendo sobre alguns frameworks Javascript, como por exemplo o [React](https://github.com/Wildhoney/ReactShadow), li algumas vezes a expressão *shadow DOM* em alguns artigos.

Parece inclusive que é possível, nas configurações de console do Chrome, ativar esse tal de *Shadow Dom*.

[image: Shadow DOM no Chrome]

Mas o que é *Shadow DOM* e pra que serve?

Tem alguma coisa a ver apenas com o Framework citado acima, ou não?

Comment: https://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/  está em inglês

Comment: Relacionado: [Google Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/) também faz uso de Shadow DOM para definir seus componentes.

Comment: Pode ser que https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM aqui tenha algo interessante, mas a página é só um rascunho

Comment: Parece estar diretamente relacionado com [Web Components](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160175/o-que-s%C3%A3o-web-components)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Shadow DOM

O ***shadow DOM***, ou *shadow tree*, é uma árvore de nós HTML assim como qualquer outra árvore que já conhecemos (a *light tree*), mas que é anexada a um elemento específico da *light tree*, não ao documento em si. Ou seja, é criado um novo contexto de nós em que todos os nós pertencentes à *shadow tree* não interagem diretamente com os nós do documento. Esta regra é válida também para o CSS (aparentemente o JavaScript não é encapsulado), ou seja, você pode definir regras no CSS utilizando ids e classes normalmente, que tais regras se aplicarão apenas ao contexto da *shadow tree* e não se aplicarão ao documento em si.

Veja o exemplo abaixo. É criado uma *shadow tree* a partir do elemento *template* e anexado ao elemento *#nameTag*. Perceba que as definições de estilo da *shadow tree* não se aplicam aos elementos externos, presentes na *light tree*.

> A classe *.outer* é definida tanto para um elemento na *light tree* quanto um elemento na *shadow tree*, porém, devido o encapsulamento das definições de estilo, apenas o elemento da *shadow tree* é estilizado.

```js
var shadow = document.querySelector('#nameTag').createShadowRoot();
var template = document.querySelector('#nameTagTemplate');
var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
shadow.appendChild(clone);
```

```html
<div class="outer">Stack Overflow em Português</div>
<div id="nameTag">Bob</div>

<template id="nameTagTemplate">
  <style>
  .outer { border: 2px solid brown; }
  </style>
  
  <div class="outer">
    <span class="boilerplate">
      Olá! Meu nome é
    </span>
    <span class="name">
      Bob
    </span>
  </div>
</template>
```

O conceito de ***shadow DOM*** faz parte dos quatro padrões de *Web Component*, junto com [modelos HTML](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/), [elementos personalizados](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements?hl=pt-br) e [importações de HTML](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/).

> Os outros três podem outras perguntas semelhantes a esta aqui no SOpt, acredito eu.

### Terminologia

A composição do Shadow DOM introduz vários conceitos básicos novos no desenvolvimento da Web. Antes de entrarmos em detalhes, vamos padronizar a terminologia para falarmos o mesmo idioma.

#### Light DOM

A marcação escrita por um usuário do seu componente. Esse DOM reside fora do shadow DOM do componente. Ele consiste nos filhos reais do elemento.

```
<button is="better-button">
  <!-- the image and span are better-button's light DOM -->
  <img src="gear.svg" slot="icon">
  <span>Settings</span>
</button>
```

#### Shadow DOM

O DOM escrito pelo autor do componente. O *Shadow DOM* é local em relação ao componente e define sua estrutura interna e o CSS com escopo, bem como encapsula os detalhes da sua implementação. Além disso, ele define como renderizar marcação criada pelo consumidor do seu componente.

```
#shadow-root
  <style>...</style>
  <slot name="icon"></slot>
  <span id="wrapper">
    <slot>Button</slot>
  </span>
```

#### Árvore plana do DOM (*plane tree*)

O resultado da distribuição do *light DOM* do usuário pelo navegador no *shadow DOM*, renderizando o produto final. A árvore plana é o que você finalmente verá no DevTools e o que será renderizado na página.

```
<button is="better-button">
  #shadow-root
    <style>...</style>
    <slot name="icon">
      <img src="gear.svg" slot="icon">
    </slot>
    <slot>
      <span>Settings</span>
    </slot>
</button>
```

---

## Posso Usar (*Can I Use?*)

### [Shadow DOM v0](http://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdom)

[image: Can i use? Shadow DOM v0]

### [Shadow DOM v1](http://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdomv1)

[image: Can i use? Shadow DOM v1]

> Tenha mais informações sobre a compatibilidade de navegadores e *polyfills* [aqui](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom?hl=pt-br#support).

---

**Fonte**:

- [Especificação W3C](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/)
- [Shadow DOM v1: Componentes da Web Independentes](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom?hl=pt-br)

Comment: Excelente resposta +1

Comment: Achei a resposta mais fácil de entender, mas nesse trecho  *"Ou seja, é criado um novo contexto de nós em que todos os nós pertencentes à shadow tree não interagem diretamente com os nós do documento."*, não sei se está tentando dizer que "documento" é o documento raíz da página ou o documento parente da sombra. (Se for esse o caso, então a sombra interior não se interage com a exterior?).

Comment: @Matheus, o documento é o documento raiz da página. A interação dos elementos contidos na *shadow tree* se limita ao elemento *host*, isto é, o elemento da *light tree* ao qual foram associados. Prova disso é que se você ler sobre a propagação de eventos, qualquer evento gerado na *shadow tree* será mapeado para o elemento *host* da *light tree*. Por exemplo, se houver um `button` na *shadow tree* do elemento `my-component` e eu clicá-lo, o evento que será propagado é o `click` do elemento `my-component`, não do `button` em si.

Comment: Pode ler sobre isso nos tópicos [O modelo de eventos do Shadow DOM](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom?hl=pt-br#events) e [Processamento de foco](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom?hl=pt-br#focus).