# Qual é a utilidade do :host, :host() e :host-context()

Tags: css, pseudo-classes

Qual é a utilidade das pseudo classes `:host`, `:host()` e `:host-context()`? Se possível com algum exemplo prático

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pseudo-classes `:host`, `:host()` e `:host-context()` fazem parte da especificação [CSS Scoping Module Level 1](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping/), que são usadas como seletores de elementos definidos dentro do **shadow DOM**.

Por consequência disto, só funcionam dentro do shadow DOM. Por isso será usado um exemplo de elemento customizado para criar um [shadow DOM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/190220/o-que-%c3%a9-shadow-dom), e demonstrar o uso destes seletores:

```js
class Guilhermento extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    let style = document.createElement('style');
    let span = document.createElement('span');
    span.textContent = 'sou filho do';

    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    shadowRoot.appendChild(style);
    shadowRoot.appendChild(span);

    style.textContent = `
      span:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      } 

      :host-context(div):after {
        content: "  div";
      }

      :host-context(span):after {
        content: "  span"; 
      }

      :host-context(div,span) {
        color: blue;
      }

      :host-context(.mudacor){ 
        color: green;
      }

      :host(.mudacor) { 
        color : red; 
      }

      :host {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); 
      }
    `;
  }
}

window.customElements.define('gui-lher-me', Guilhermento);
```

```html
<div>
  <gui-lher-me></gui-lher-me> azul
</div>

<div class="mudacor">
  <gui-lher-me></gui-lher-me> verde
</div>

<span>
  <gui-lher-me></gui-lher-me> azul
</span>

<p>
  <gui-lher-me class="mudacor"></gui-lher-me> vermelho
</p>
```

O seletor [:host](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host), seleciona o nódulo raiz do shadow DOM, que no caso pode ser representado por `<gui-lher-me>`. No exemplo ele é responsável por mudar a cor do fundo.

O seletor [:host()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host()), seleciona o nódulo raiz do shadow DOM, que atende aos requisitos especificados. No exemplo ele é responsável por mudar a cor do texto para vermelho.

O seletor [:host-context()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host-context()), seleciona o nódulo raiz do shadow DOM que possui o elemento pai, que atende aos requisitos especificados. No exemplo ele é responsável por mudar a cor do texto para azul ou verde, e adicionar textos adicionais.

**NOTA:** A especificação é um pouco mais complicada do que expliquei anteriormente.  O nódulo raiz do shadow DOM é chamado na especificação de nódulo anfitrião, que é o nódulo raiz depois que o navegador (browser) injeta o shadow DOM no elemento customizado dentro do DOM do documento (ou seja, após a união do shadow DOM com o document DOM).

> Qual é a utilidade das pseudo classes... ?

**Resposta:** Facilita a definição de regras que afetam elementos do shadow DOM. Principalmente regras que dependem da relação pai & filho.

Comment: Guilhermeto ou Guilherme?

Comment: Guilhermento = Guilherme + Elemento; //eu acho que Guilhermelemento ficaria muito grande, mas é uma opção :)

Comment: `:host` e `gui-lher-me` São equivalentes? É possível ter múltiplos elementos (guilhermento1, guilhermento2, ...)? Se sim, esses seletores mudaria o estilo de todos elementos? É possível usar `.mudacor:host` em vez de `:host(.mudacor)`? Se sim, qual a diferença? É possível usar `.mudacor gui-lher-me` em vez de `:host-context(.mudacor)`? Se sim, qual a diferença?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam a resposta é: 1=não e sim (depende do contexto); 2=sim; 3=a princípio não, mas parece ser possível (não que eu recomende); 4=não; 5=ver reposta 4; 6=sim; 7=um faz mudança usando CSS externo, e outro faz de dentro do elemento customizado.