# Para que serve a tag head no html?

Tags: html, html-tags

Eu estou lendo [um livro](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032977.do) que em determinado momento diz o seguinte:

> *"Agora precisamos de um lugar para colocar nossos templates - uma maneira é usar um elemento existente no nosso HTML, de preferência escondido. Você pode conseguir isso usando o elemento `<script>` dentro de `<head>`."*

- Para que serve a tag `<head>`?
- Qual a diferença entre colocar algo na `<head>` e em outros lugares?
- Existe algum comportamento específico que só acontece na `<head>` e que não pode ser reproduzido usando o resto da página?

O autor segue:

> *"Pode parecer estranho no início - mas funciona muito bem."*

- Por que seria estranho usar essa tag para esse fim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Para que serve a tag `<head>`?

O elemento `head` representa uma coleção de metadados para o documento. Metadados são, como o próprio nome diz, dados sobre os dados. De forma resumida, você poderá informar o navegador alguns detalhes sobre o conteúdo da página. Por exemplo, `<meta charset="UTF-8">` você está especificando a coleção de caracteres que o navegador deve utilizar para analisar sua página. Você ainda pode especificar o autor, descrever o conteúdo da página, ter configurações para SEO, informar folhas de estilos para o navegador utilizar na renderização da página, etc. Toda a documentação, incluindo todos os elementos possíveis para a tag `head` você encontra [aqui](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-head-element) (1).

> Qual a diferença entre colocar algo na `<head>` e em outros lugares?

Por padrão, todos os elementos presentes dentro da `head` não são exibidos pelo navegador. Comportamento esperado, visto que o elemento tem como finalidade definir metadados e não dados da página. Os *templates* que o autor citam são da biblioteca [*Handlebars*](http://handlebarsjs.com/), portanto, não são conteúdos que serão renderizados diretamente ao usuário, mas sim, conteúdos que estarão disponíveis para o JavaScript utilizar futuramente (quando executado). Acredito que o autor apenas define esses *templates* dentro do elemento `head` por não serem renderizados, mas qualquer conteúdo dentro do elemento `script` que não possui o [MIME Type de JavaScript](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#scriptingLanguages) são desconsiderados pelo navegador ao renderizar a página. Portanto, um elemento definido como abaixo, dentro do elemento `body`, funcionaria da mesma maneira.

```html
<body>
  <h1>Renderizado</h1>
  <script type="text/html">
    <h1>Não renderizado</h1>
  </script>
</body>
```

Para deixar ainda mais específico, você pode utilizar `type="text/template"`:

```html
<body>
  <h1>Renderizado</h1>
  <script type="text/template">
    Aqui está meu {{template}}.
  </script>
</body>
```

> Existe algum comportamento específico que só acontece na `<head>` e que não pode ser reproduzido usando o resto da página?

Para este caso, não. Quando não se trata de metadados, eu particularmente acho que fica mais semântico incluir no elemento `body`, pois o *template* faz parte do conteúdo do documento, só não é exibido.

#### Elemento `template`

Existe ainda o elemento [`template`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) que é definido justamente para este fim. Seu conteúdo é ignorado pelo navegador ao renderizar a página e pode ser acessado via JavaScript.

```html
<h1>Renderizado</h1>

<template id="h1">
  <h1>Não renderizado</h1>
</template>
```

Acredito que hoje o ideal é utilizar este elemento ao invés do `script`. Inclusive, [web components](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160175/o-que-s%C3%A3o-web-components) utilizam esta tag geralmente. O framework [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/) eu sei que usa. Ler também sobre [shadow dom](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/190220/o-que-%C3%A9-shadow-dom).

#### Referências

1. [The head element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-head-element)
2. [The script element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element)