# Porque se declara uma class ou id nas tags script e link?

Tags: html, html-tags

Várias vezes vejo codificação nas tags `<script>`/`<link>` que possuem *class*:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" class="main-stylesheet">
```

Ou até mesmo com *id*:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ace.css" id="ace-style" />
```

Ou com os dois incorporados:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace.min.css" class="ace-main-stylesheet" id="main-ace-style" />
```

- Porque e qual a função de utilizar uma *class* ou *id* nessas tags?
- Quando recomenda-se utilizar *class* e/ou *id*?

<sub>Talvez um exemplo de uso mais visível ajude a compreender melhor.</sub>

Comment: Em estilos é provavelmente para usar o atributo `disabled` para poder tipo mudar um tema dinamicamente sem precisar de "refresh", agora na tag script realmente não consigo enxergar nenhuma utilidade.

Comment: É só pesquisar no código fonte da página que viu isso e verificar o objetivo. Os atributos `id` e `class` funcionam como em qualquer outro elemento e é muito difícil dizer quando é utilizado. Basicamente, é utilizado quando precisa selecionar os elementos de forma dinâmica. O porquê de fazer isso pode variar muito.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, particularmente foi a primeira vez que eu vi e achei realmente muito estranho tal codificação. Resolvi perguntar para ver se alguém já tinha tratado com tal assunto. Obrigado pela explicação também

Comment: Estou respondendo com algo mais concreto.

Comment: Já utilizei id no style. Motivo, disponibilizei ao cliente poder trocar o tema da página. Então, tinha um array no js com vários estilos e ele selecionava via interface qual queria, depois apenas fazia referência via ID o style e colocava a URL do arquivo desejado, assim mudando toda a interface. Lembrei que, também já utilizei ID no script pra verificar se foi inserido um determinado arquivo .js. Caso não houvesse a inserção do mesmo, inseria via CDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A exata função dos atributos só poderia ser dada ao analisar o código da aplicação em questão, porém, abaixo cito algumas possíveis aplicações destes atributos nestes elementos.

Os atributos `id` e `class` são [atributos globais](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes), o que significa que a função será sempre a mesma para qualquer elemento, sem exceção. Ou seja, o `id` irá definir um identificador único para o elemento, que deve ser único também no documento. Já o `class` define identificadores que não necessitam ser únicos, utilizado quando deseja identificar um grupo semelhante de elementos.

**Mas por quê utilizar estes atributos em `link` e `script`?**

Como comentado, as aplicações podem variar bastante conforme a necessidade de cada desenvolvedor e/ou aplicação. Para o elemento `link` o Guilherme [comentou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/226661/porque-se-declara-uma-class-ou-id-nas-tags-script-e-link/226734#comment464243_226661) a aplicação mais óbvia: trocar dinamicamente o estilo da página.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("changeStyleButton");
const css = document.getElementById("cssFile");

btn.addEventListener("click", event => {
  let href = css.getAttribute("href");
  
  css.setAttribute("href", (href == "style.css") ? "other.css" : "style.css");
  
  console.log("O CSS mudou de " + href + " para " + css.getAttribute("href"));
});
```

```html
<link id="cssFile" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button id="changeStyleButton">Alterar estilo</button>
```

Considerando que ambos os arquivos, `style.css` e `other.css`, existem, o estilo da página atual irá ser alterado ao pressionar o botão. Porém, para o elemento `script` isso não faz muito sentido - pode até ser que alguma aplicação ou problema possam fazer uso desta troca de arquivos, mas sinceramente eu nunca vi necessidade. Mas tem uma aplicação utilizando o elemento `script` que é bem interessante: a Shadow DOM.

[O que é shadow DOM?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190220/5878)

A construção de *Web Components* se dá pela inserção de elementos na *shadow DOM* de outro elemento, basicamente, e como o objetivo é trabalhar com a *shadow DOM* não faz sentido você definir tais elementos na *light DOM*. As opções são: você criar os elementos dinamicamente com JavaScript ao definir a *shadow DOM*, o que pode ser bastante trabalhoso, ou criar o DOM fora da *light DOM*, dentro do `meta` e apenas copiá-lo para a *shadow DOM*. Esta segunda solução faz uso do elemento `script type="text/template"` e você precisará definir o atributo `id` para poder selecionar o DOM futuramente.

```js
const element = document.getElementById("foo").createShadowRoot();
const shadow = document.getElementById('shadowDOM');

element.innerHTML = shadow.innerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>

<script id="shadowDOM" type="text/template">
  <h1>Elemento na Shadow DOM</h1>
</script>
```

Para provar que o conteúdo é inserido na *Shadow DOM*, basta analisar com o inspetor do navegador:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Vale citar que a partir do HTML 5 há o elemento `template` que substitui o uso do elemento `script` para a criação de DOM fora da *light DOM*. Eu comento sobre isso nesta resposta:

[Para que serve a tag head no html?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199703/5878)