# Há algum problema em usar tags e atributos inventados?

Tags: html, html5

Estava olhando alguns sites e percebi algumas tags que não são padrões como `<div>` `<span>` etc...

Então resolvi testar e vi que essas tags funcionam normalmente com css e javascript, mas isso me deixou com uma duvida. Há algum problema em usar essas tags e atributos "inventados"?

```js
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("nomedatag")[0];
el.textContent = el.getAttribute("nomedoatributo");
```

```css
nomedatag{
  display:block;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background-color:#333;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<nomedatag nomedoatributo="Texto"></nomedatag>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se vc testar um `custom elements` desses no validador de código da própria W3C vc vai ver que vai retornar um erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Link para vc mesmo testar: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

---

**Propriedades do user-agent**

A maioria das tag como `<div>`, `<label>`, etc possuem atributos default definidos pelo próprio `user-agent` como por exemplo `display:block` na `div`. Já um `custom elemen`t como `<teste>` não vai receber estilo algum do `user-agent`, o que na maioria dos casos tb não é muito útil...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Não normativo**

**Custom Elements** ainda são um *Draft* na especificações do HTML5 como vc pode consultar aqui http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/

> *"Embora os autores sempre possam usar elementos não padrão em seus documentos, com o comportamento específico do aplicativo adicionado após o fato por script ou similar, esses elementos têm sido historicamente não-conformes e não muito funcionais."*

---

**Boas práticas e Semântica**

> *"Em geral, o nome do elemento a ser alargada não pode ser determinado simplesmente por olhar para o interface do elemento estende-se, como muitos elementos partilham a mesma interface (por exemplo, `q` e `blockquote` ambos compartilhando `HTMLQuoteElement`)."*

Para usar nosso elemento interno personalizado, usamos o atributo `is` em um elemento `button`:

```
<button is="plastic-button">Click Me!</button>
```

---

**Desvantagem** de se usar esse tipo de elemento: http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#drawbacks-of-autonomous-custom-elements

- Mal gerenciamento do `tabindex`
- Semântica comprometida, necessita de `role` e `aria atributos`, diferente de um  `article`, `section`, etc que já têm uma semântica intrínseca da própria tag
- Não tem os estilos do `user-agent`

Answer (score 3):

No HTML5, o uso de tags "inventadas" não é recomendado, exceto se você estiver usando tecnologias como [`WebComponents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Web_Components). Saiba mais sobre eles [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160175/o-que-s%C3%A3o-web-components).

Em relação às tags da especificação do HTML (como `<div>`, `<span>`, `<section>`, etc), você pode criar atributos personalizados desde que eles sigam o padrão `data-*`, por exemplo:

```
<span data-person-age="16">Luiz Felipe</span>
```

Caso contrário, irá quebrar a validação do HTML do seu site.

Comment: Eu fiquei maravilhado na época do lançamento do HTML5 com o atributo ```data-*``` . A partir daí passei a usar muito ela para controles específicos de tags em conjunto com o jQuery para manipulação visual dos sistemas que desenvolvi.